Can you create 'User Flows' in Azure with a pay-as-you-go account
I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: enable auth web api and here set up user flows
i have a pay-as-you-go account and I don't see the 'user flows' option anywhere in the AAD B2C UI.
Any advice?

Could you please check and confirm whether you created B2C tenant or not? Please include Portal images where you are checking.

Did you follow this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant

Yes - you can pay with a Pay-As-You-Go account but it only costs money with MFA or > 50000 MAU

@Sridevi are you telling me that the default tenant is not B2C? maybe that's my issue. honestly i don't know if i need B2C. all my users are internal.

Yes, your default tenant is not B2C. You need to create it separately by following MS document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin. To create B2C user flows, having B2C tenant is mandatory.

it turns out i didn't need a B2C tenant. i was following the wrong tutorial

Yes, you can create  'User Flows' in Azure with a pay-as-you-go account. Make sure to switch to created B2C directory to find User flows option.
Initially, I created one demo Azure AD B2C tenant in pay-as-you-go account by following this MS Document.

If you are checking for 'User Flows' option in below screen of local Azure AD tenant, it won't be having that option:

To find 'User Flows' option, make sure to switch to newly created Azure AD B2C directory as below:

After switching to Azure AD B2C directory, you can see  'User Flows' option and create them successfully like this:

